# robot_pose_ekf won't publish any messages

Tags: ros, kalman-filter, ekf, sensor-fusion

I am having trouble getting the robot_pose_ekf package to publish messages. I launch it with this launch file.

```
<launch>

  <!-- Extended Kalman Filter from robot_pose_ekf Node-->
  <!-- Subscribe: /odom, /imu/data, /vo -->
  <!-- Publish: /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined -->

  <remap from="/imu_data" to="/imu/data" />

  <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">
    <param name="output_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_footprint"/>
    <param name="freq" value="30.0"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="odom_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
    <param name="vo_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="gps_used" value="false"/>
    <param name="debug" value="true"/>
    <param name="self_diagnose" value="true"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

But then I get lots of these errors:

```
[ WARN] [1636570848.059506230]: MSG to TF: Quaternion Not Properly Normalized
[ERROR] [1636570848.059787913]: Covariance specified for measurement on topic imu is zero
[ERROR] [1636570848.060134410]: filter time older than odom message buffer
[ WARN] [1636570848.074015563]: MSG to TF: Quaternion Not Properly Normalized
[ERROR] [1636570848.074583539]: Covariance specified for measurement on topic imu is zero
[ERROR] [1636570848.085433183]: Covariance specified for measurement on topic wheelodom is zero
```

And I get this output from wtf, which says I'm getting inputs but am not publishing any messages on topic /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined.

doug@raspi4:~$ rosrun robot_pose_ekf wtf.py
looking for node robot_pose_ekf...
Input:

- Odometry sensor

  - is used
  - is active
  - received 12 messages
  - listens to topic /odom
- IMU sensor

  - is used
  - is active
  - received 152 messages
  - listens to topic /imu/data
- Visual Odometry sensor

  - is NOT used
  - is NOT active
  - received 0 messages
  - listens to topic
- GPS sensor

  - is NOT used
  - is NOT active
  - received 0 messages
  - listens to topic
    Output:
- Robot pose ekf filter

  - is active
  - sent 0 messages
  - publishes on topics /robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined and /tf

My IMU data is coming from a BNO055 device publishing with code from https://github.com/RoboticArts/ros_imu_bno055.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Hi, can you echo your IMU topic because the error is coming due to the zero covariance matrix of your IMU data.

Comment: ```
doug@raspi4:~$ rostopic echo /imu/data -n1
header: 
  seq: 1
  stamp: 
    secs: 1636710493
    nsecs: 828954696
  frame_id: "imu_link"
orientation: 
  x: 95.0
  y: 111.0
  z: 0.0
  w: 16383.0
orientation_covariance: [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
angular_velocity: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular_velocity_covariance: [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 0.0
  y: -0.03
  z: 0.0
linear_acceleration_covariance: [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```